# Remove duplicate vectors inside a vector of vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a vector of vector (`loops`) which contains integer values. Some inside vectors are duplicating but their element order is not the same. Now, I want to get a vector of vector without having any duplicate inner vectors. 
here is an example for my vec of vec;

loops = ((9 18 26 11 9), (9 11 26 18 9),(9 18 25 16 9),(11 45 26 11),( 11 26 45 11),( 16 49 25 16),( 16 25 49 16),(18 9 11 26 18),( 18 9 16 25 18),( 25 16 49 25),( 26 11 45 26))

To identify whether any inner vector is a duplicate of another inner vector; I have developed a function `IsDuplicate`. This tells me, `(9 18 26 11 9) and (9 11 26 18 9)` are duplicates then I can delete the second or all other duplicates.

To remove duplicate vectors inside my vector of vector, I have implemented following codes.

```
Vector<vector<int> > loops;
Vector<vector<int> > ::iterator no1, no2;
Int setno1, setno2;

for (no1=loops.begin(), setno1=0; no1!=loops.end(); no1++, setno1++){
       set1 = *no1;
       for (no2=loops.begin()+setno1, setno2=setno1; no2!=loops.end(); setno2++){
            set2 = *no2;
            if (set2.IsDuplicate(set1))  loops.erase(loops.begin()+setno2);
            else no2++;
       }

  }
```

it took very very long time and i thought my program is crasihing. so, Please help me to rectify this issue.

also, i tried with this. this works but i got a wrong answer. any help please.

```
01   int first=0; bool duplicates=false;  
02   do {     
03        set1 = loops[first];     
04        for (no2=loops.begin()+1, setno2=1;  no2!=loops.end();  setno2++){     
05             set2 = *no2;      
06             if (set2.IsPartOf(set1)){      
07                 loops.erase(loops.begin()+setno2);     
08                 duplicates = true;      
09             }      
10             else no2++;     
11        }      
12        first++;      
13       } while(!duplicates);
```

Comment: "crashed" how? Uncaught exception? Segmentation fault, maybe?

Comment: Why not make a vector of sets or multisets? Then it'd be much easier to identify duplicates. Or even a set of sets.

Comment: @KerrekSB Are the sets (1,1,2) and (1,2,2) equal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to use the [Erase/Remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) with a custom predicate.
To check for duplicate vectors and without modifying the contents of your vectors, write a predicate that takes its arguments by value, sort the vectors and use `std::equal`.

```
bool equal_vector(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b) {
  std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
  std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());

  return std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
}

// use it like this
v.erase( remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), equal_vector), v.end() );
```

As to why your current code fails: Erasing an element from a `vector` invalidates all other iterators to that vector that are currently in existence thus `vector::erase` returns a valid iterator to the position after the element that has been removed.

The stdlib also provides the `set` and `multiset` container which look like a much better fit for your purpose.

Comment: thanks for the response. but me, i am using DevC++ and i can not use idiomatic way (I tried to use that way earlier to remove elements inside a vector, but could do. so i hope, dev cannot recognise these idioms.), if you can, please add the traditional way to do the same thing. then, i can learn and implement.  Also, i can not use set as my real objct class is not integer (it is my own class PointNumber) but inherited from integers and posted as interger for the simplicity. - thanks in advance-

Comment: @g_niro I have no experience with DevC++, but this seems impossible. Do you include the right headers? You need at least `algorithm` and `vector` for the above to work. If the `algorithm` header doesn't support `remove` or `sort` you should switch to a viable platform ASAP.

Comment: @g_niro Also the `int` and `PointNumber` difference does in no way affect that code as long as `PointNumber` has `operator<` defined.

Comment: @g_niro So, I don't get what is keeping this solution from working for you. You might want to show us the code and the errors in a separate question.

Comment: sorry, i could say you, i cant change my element order as i need this orderd values later. (i guess, no way to use sort).

Comment: @pmr I think that `equal_vector` should be UnaryPredicate, as stated in doc of [remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). How did you manage to make it to compare the elements?