# Remove duplicate vectors from vector of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am trying to implement the solution to the problem found at [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626273/remove-duplicate-vectors-inside-a-vector-of-vector).

Here is my snippet of code

```
bool compareVec(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    return std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
}
vector<vector<int> > ans;
ans.erase(std::remove_if(ans.begin(), ans.end(), compareVec), ans.end());
```

I am getting the following errors

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of 
'_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, 
_RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with 
_RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, 
std::vector<std::vector<int> > >; _Predicate = bool (*)(std::vector<int>, 
std::vector<int>)]':

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4465:41:   required from '_IIter   
std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = 
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>
 > >; _Predicate = bool (*)(std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>)]'

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:1144:64:   required from '_FIter 
std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter = 
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int> 
> >; _Predicate = bool (*)(std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>)]'

solution.cpp:40:64:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:214:23: error: too few arguments to    
function
if (__pred(*__first))
                   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:218:23: error: too few arguments to   
function
if (__pred(*__first))
                   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:222:23: error: too few arguments to 
function
if (__pred(*__first))
                   ^
```

Can anyone help me out in debugging this?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The elements of vector are sorted and all these vectors are also sorted.

Unique also gives an error. I am unable to figure out why?

Why is the example given in the link I provided, not helpful here?

Comment: Your `compareVec` is currently making a copy of both vectors to compare each time it's called. *cringe*. Take them by const reference instead.

Comment: Also, the callable that you pass to `remove_if` should only take one argument. You can achieve what you need with a lambda that captures. Also, this isn't how to remove duplicates properly. [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1041620/27678)

Comment: Are you compiling C++11 or greater?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Both the answers are useful, but the first one is easier to understand, so marking it correct. +1 for AndyG's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::remove_if` requires a **unary** predicate.  You pass a **binary** predicate, which causes your errors (`/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:222:23: error: too few arguments to function` → your function takes *two* arguments, not *one*). 
Further, `std::remove_if` does its removals with no consideration of other elements (which is why it accepts a *unary* predicate), so it isn't actually what you're looking for.

What you want to use is `std::unique`, which *does* require the `compareVec` you've implemented.  However, `std::vector` already provides the `operator==` overload, so that implementation is actually redundant!  Also, you say that you get an error when using `std::unique`.  Try passing your parameters as `const&`.

---

Thus, when your outer vector and inner vectors are already sorted, the solution is as it'd be for any other vector of sorted elements:

```
outer.erase(std::unique(outer.begin(), outer.end()), outer.end());
```

Comment: `std::vector` has both an `operator<` and `operator==` defined so they can be compared directly without needing `std::lexicographical_compare` or `std::equal`

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Okay, since this is not marked with C++11, I will use a functor instead of a lambda.</strike>

The first problem you have is that [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) takes a UnaryPredicate, which means it should only accept a single argument.

The second issue is also related to your understanding of `remove_if`. After you fix `compareVec` to only accept one argument, you're left wondering how you could possibly compare all elements against each other.

You could approach this one of two ways:

- Sort your vector of vectors (`<` operator is defined lexicographically for `vector`) and then use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) ([Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector)) ([More examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7626374/27678)).

  - In the link you provided (same as the one I just linked to), notice that they sort first, and you do not.
- Or, if there's no clear definition of `<` for your elements, only `==`, you could perform an O(N<sup>2</sup>) lookup/erase on each subsequent item (shown below):

Comparison functor (could make as a lambda in C++11 and greater)

```
struct CompareVec
{
    CompareVec(const std::vector<int>& _in) : compare_against(_in){}

    bool operator()(const std::vector<int>& rhs) const
    {
        return compare_against == rhs;
    };

    const std::vector<int>& compare_against;
};
```

To be used like so:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < ans.size(); ++i)
{
    CompareVec comparator(ans[i]);
    ans.erase(std::remove_if(ans.begin()+i+1, ans.end(), comparator), ans.end());
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0aded6e1c460e6e3) (Compiled in C++11 for want of initializing test vectors with initializer lists)

---

### Edit

In C++11 we can get rid of the `CompareVec` functor and replace it with a lambda:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < ans.size(); ++i)
{
    ans.erase(std::remove_if(ans.begin()+i+1, ans.end(), 
    [&ans, &i](const std::vector<int>& _rhs)
    { 
        return ans[i] == _rhs;
    }) , ans.end());
}
```

[Demo2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bf8d2b1016a6df9)

Comment: Why do we need a loop for i? For std::unique, we just wrote the a single statement?

Comment: `std::equal` only makes sense here if both containers are the same size. It's probably simpler to just say `return compare_against == rhs;`

Comment: @AndyG: `std::equal` will happily read past the end of a container if the first range is larger. If it's shorter it stops too early. C++14 is adding a two-range overload that gracefully handles unequal length ranges.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: And, you're right. I was mistaken when I read the documentation for it. The versions that allow differently sized containers are C++14 only *and* I should have provided begin and end for the second container.

Comment: @LearningToCode: `unique` only removes adjacent equivalent items. Unless your vector of vectors is sorted, it's useless.